# Filtering array of objects by searching nested object property

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have 1 array of objects(named childrenArray) like so :

```
[
  {name:'somevalue',favColors:['red','purple','green']},
  {name:'somevalue1',favColors:['blue','brown','pink]},
  {name:'somevalue2',favColors:['orange','yellow']}
]
```

And an object with the following properties:

```
{colorBook:'somevalue4', colors:['red','blue']}
```

Essentially I want to filter the array of objects to return the objects that have common color properties with  my object.

So  a search for the colors property would result in

```
{name:'somevalue',favColors:['red','purple','green']},
{name:'somevalue1',favColors:['blue','brown','pink]},
```

What I've tried so far:

```
 getElementsByColors(colors: string[]){
     return _.filter(this.childrenArray, function(child) {
        child.favColors.find( color => color === colors.forEach(c => c)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the `childrenArray` by checking with `Array.some()` if it contains at least one color (or every for all of them) and `Array.includes()`:

```js
const childrenArray = [
  {name:'somevalue',favColors:['red','purple','green']},
  {name:'somevalue1',favColors:['blue','brown','pink']},
  {name:'somevalue2',favColors:['orange','yellow']}
]

const getElementsByColors = ({ colors }) =>
  childrenArray.filter(({ favColors }) =>
    colors.some(color => favColors.includes(color)) // or every for all of them
  )

const result = getElementsByColors({colorBook:'somevalue4', colors:['red','blue']})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

In lodash this would look very similar with the use of [*.some*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#some), [.filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter) and [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#includes):

```js
const data = [ {name:'somevalue',favColors:['red','purple','green']}, {name:'somevalue1',favColors:['blue','brown','pink']}, {name:'somevalue2',favColors:['orange','purple', 'green']} ]
const filter1 = {colorBook:'somevalue4', colors:['red','blue']}
const filter2 = {colorBook:'somevalue4', colors:['purple','green']}

let matchSomeColors = (d, f) => 
  _.filter(d, ({favColors}) => _.some(f.colors, c => _.includes(favColors, c)))

let matchEveryColor = (d, f) => 
  _.filter(d, ({favColors}) => _.every(f.colors, c => _.includes(favColors, c)))

console.log('some: ', matchSomeColors(data, filter1))
console.log('every: ', matchEveryColor(data, filter2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

I added also [_.every](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#every) so you can see the difference. But if you have to use lodash only for this then you are better of doing it with just plain JS etc.